# ifort -ipo flag strange behavior

Tags: performance, compiler-construction, fortran, flags

I have the following code for testing the intel mkl DAXPY routine.

```
program test
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: n = 50000000
    integer, parameter :: nloop = 100
    real(8), dimension(:), allocatable :: a, b
    integer start_t, end_t, rate, i
    allocate(a(n))
    allocate(b(n))

    a = 1.0d0
    b = 2.0d0
    call system_clock(start_t, rate)
    do i = 1, nloop
        call sumArray(a, b, a, 3.0d0, n)
    end do
    call system_clock(end_t)
    print *, sum(a)
    print *, "sumArray time: ", real(end_t-start_t)/real(rate)

    a = 1.0d0
    b = 2.0d0
    call system_clock(start_t, rate)
    do i = 1, nloop
        call daxpy(n, 3.0d0, b, 1, a, 1)
    end do
    call system_clock(end_t)
    print *, sum(a)
    print *, "daxpy time: ", real(end_t-start_t)/real(rate)

    a = 1.0d0
    b = 2.0d0
    call system_clock(start_t, rate)
    do i = 1, nloop
        a = a + 3.0d0*b
    end do
    call system_clock(end_t)
    print *, sum(a)
    print *, "a + 3*b time: ", real(end_t-start_t)/real(rate)
end program test

subroutine sumArray(x, y, z, alfa, n)
    implicit none
    integer n, i
    real(8) x(n), y(n), z(n), alfa
    !$OMP PARALLEL DO
    do i = 1, n
        z(i) = x(i) + alfa*y(i)
    end do
    !$OMP END PARALLEL DO
end subroutine sumArray
```

Here, sumArray is a handwritten subroutine with openmp that does something similar to DAXPY. 
When I compile the code with `ifort test.f90 -o test -O3 -openmp -mkl` the results are (aproximately):

```
sumArray time: 5.7 sec
daxpy time: 5.7 sec
a + 3*b time: 1.9 sec
```

However, when I compile it with `ifort test.f90 -o test -O3 -openmp -mkl -ipo` the results for `a + 3*b` change dramatically:

```
sumArray time: 5.7 sec
daxpy time: 5.7 sec
a + 3*b time: 9.3 sec
```

So firstly, why is the naive array sum better than mkl? And what does `-ipo` have to do with  the slowdown of the naive array sum? Also, what bothers me is that when I eliminate the loops, that is, when I just time each operation once, the times are just like the first case divided by 1000 (around 5.7 ms for `sumArray` and `daxpy`, 9.3 ms for `a + 3*b`) regardless of using `-ipo`. My guess is that something about the naive sum in a loop allows the compiler to optimize further, but the `-ipo` flag messes up this optimization. **Note:** I know that `-ipo` in this case is useless since it is a single file.

Comment: you do not use `a` after you sum it third time. The compiler could remove the summation loop at all...?

Comment: The actual code prints sum(a) after each loop. I just removed it for clarity. Also, even so I don't see why -ipo would have something to do with that kind of optimizations.

Comment: -ipo does even more aggressive optimization. If you had showed us the actual code, we could comment further, but I took your code and added a print of one of the elements of a after the last loop - the timing even with -ipo was larger than the previous loops. I could not reproduce the significantly smaller time you showed here. You might want to turn on optimization reports (-opt-report=3) and see if it gives you a clue.

Comment: I did a mistake in my question. The situation is inverted: the naive sum is slower when I compile with `-ipo`. I edited my question. The actual code is just like the one here plus a `print *, sum(a)` after each loop. Anyways, I added those lines now.

Comment: I didn't see a significant difference with or without -ipo. Without -ipo I get times of 8.54, 8.12, 10.20 (quad-core Core i7 965). With -ipo, 8.55, 7.77, 10.12. Are you consistently getting such a small time for the third loop without -ipo?

Comment: Yes, it is consistent. I'm running on my university's Xeon E5-2680 with CentOS, via ssh. It is very strange.

Comment: For me the third loop is faster in both cases `6.76, 6.77, 1.67` on i7-3770